# How do I add custom rounding rules depending on the price

Tags: javascript

I might not see the forest for the trees, but I have problems with rounding integers and fractionals of a price according to custom rule sets.

**Example:**

All prices (in Dollars) from 100-200 should be rounded up to either 50 or 90 cents. Also the number left of the point should be bumped up to nearest number divisional with 5.

- 101.10 ~ 105.50
- 126.40 ~ 130.50
- 144.60 ~ 145.90
- 156.60 ~ 160.90

Below is a data structure I have setup I think I might use to calculate the rounding.

```js
const data = {
  "us": [
    {
      "start": 100,
      "end": 200,
      "integer": 5,
      "decimals": [
        {"start": 0, "end": 50, "value": 50},
        {"start": 50, "end": 90, "value": 90},
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// I have made price a string so I can do split(), is there a better way?
const price = '101.10';
let priceParts = price.split('.');

for (const item of data.us) {
  if (priceParts[0] >= item.start && priceParts[0] <= item.end) {
    // Round up priceParts[0] with item.integer
    // Obviously below is incorrect, but I was hoping you guys have a neat function for it
    priceParts[0] = Number(priceParts[0]) + item.integer

    for (const decimal of item.decimals) {
      if (priceParts[1] <= decimal.start && priceParts[1] >= decimal.end) {
        // Round up priceParts[1] with decimal.value
        priceParts[1] = decimal.value;
      }
    }
  }
}

const newPrice = Number(priceParts.join('.')).toFixed(2);

// newPrice = 106.90
console.log(newPrice);
```

- How would you solve it?
- Am I on the right track?
- Is there already a library out there that does this (the ones I find on Google seems not to be a good fit)?

Comment: If it works, you're on the right track. But that said, Numbers are for calculations and Strings are for display. Generally speaking, you should not switch between them.  I would just set the price as a number initially and make use of Math functions to gather what you need to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where not that far of with the following line to "round" up to the following `item.integer`.

> ```
> priceParts[0] = Number(priceParts[0]) + item.integer
> ```

The only thing missing is subtracting the remainder when you divide the integer by `item.integer`.

```
const integer   = Number(priceParts[0]);
const remainder = integer % item.integer;
priceParts[0]   = integer + item.integer - remainder;
```

Let's look at an example:

```
// say number = 12 and you want to round up to multiples of 5
const remainder = 12 % 5;     // 2
const result    = 12 + 5 - 2; // 15
```

There are two issues with the above solution. If the remainder is `0`, which happens at 0, 5, 10, 15, etc. you do not want to add the `5` to the number. Otherwise `10` would round up to `15` and `15` would round up to `20`.

So if the remainder is `0` (falsy) we use just the number since it's already dividable by `item.integer`. Meaning that the above becomes:

```
const integer   = Number(priceParts[0]);
const remainder = integer % item.integer;

if (remainder) {
  priceParts[0] = integer + item.integer - remainder;
} else {
  priceParts[0] = integer;
}
```

The other issue is that **the above assumes that the input number is positive**. If negative numbers can be provided you must change:

```
const remainder = integer % item.integer;
```

Into:

```
const modulo = ((integer % item.integer) + item.integer) % item.integer;
```

This is because `-12` does have a remainder of `-2`, so if you where to follow the same principal you would get `-12 + 5 - -2 = -5`. For negative number we need the modulo. The modulo of `-12` is `3` resulting in `-12 + 5 - 3 = -10`.

See the description of the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) for details.

---

A simpler solution is to use the build in `Math.floor()`, `Math.round()` or `Math.ceil()` which do the rounding for you. Because it rounds to the nearest integer we'll have to convert the integer into "multiple of 5" number, round it, and finally convert it back to a normal integer.

```
priceParts[0] = Math.ceil(Number(priceParts[0]) / item.integer) * item.integer;
```

The nice thing here is that there are no weird rounding scenario's for multiples of `item.integer` (5 here) or negative numbers.

---

With the integer rounding out of the way I would personally use a different approach. Instead focusing on the string representation of a decimal you can do this entirely with the number value.

You can get the integer part of a number with `Math.floor(number)` and you can get the decimals using `(number - integer) * 100`. Instead of joining the two parts together, the decimals could just be added to the integer if you divide them by 100.

The snippet below uses [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search through the array of rules to find the one matching the criteria.

```js
function createRound(rules) {
  return function round(num) {
    const int = Math.floor(num);
    const dec = (num - int) * 100;

    const rule = rules.find(({start, end}) => num >= start && num <= end);
    if (!rule) return num; // or throw error
    
    const decRule = rule.decimals
      .find(({start, end}) => dec >= start && dec <= end)
      || { value: dec }; // or throw error
    
    return Math.ceil(int / rule.integer) * rule.integer
         + decRule.value / 100;
  };
}

const data = {
  "us": [
    {
      "start": 100,
      "end": 200,
      "integer": 5,
      "decimals": [
        {"start":  0, "end": 50, "value": 50},
        {"start": 50, "end": 90, "value": 90},
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const round = createRound(data.us);

console.log(round(101.10)); // 105.50
console.log(round(126.40)); // 130.50
console.log(round(144.60)); // 145.90
console.log(round(156.60)); // 160.90

console.log(round( 12.34)); //  12.34 (no rule)
console.log(round(156.95)); // 160.95 (no decimal rule)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the integer part as `parseInt(price)` and the decimal part as the price minus the integer part. Then for the decimal part you need to only find the first group that matches the bounds, and use those values to adjust it.

something like

```js
const data = {
  "us": [{
    "start": 100,
    "end": 200,
    "integer": 5,
    "decimals": [{
        "start": 0,
        "end": 50,
        "value": 50
      },
      {
        "start": 50,
        "end": 90,
        "value": 90
      },
    ]
  }]
};

const price = 101.10;
let integerPart = parseInt(price);
let decimalPart = (price - integerPart) * 100;

for (const item of data.us) {
  if (integerPart > item.start && integerPart <= item.end) {
    const needsAdjustment = integerPart % item.integer > 0;
    
    if (needsAdjustment) {
      integerPart = (parseInt(integerPart / item.integer) + 1) * item.integer
    }

    const decimalLimitGroup = item.decimals.find(decimalLimit => decimalPart >= decimalLimit.start && decimalPart <= decimalLimit.end);

    if (decimalLimitGroup) {
      decimalPart = decimalLimitGroup.value
    }
  }
}

const newPrice = (integerPart + (decimalPart / 100)).toFixed(2);

// newPrice = 106.90
console.log(newPrice);
```